# Surely residual = value less predicted, even in GLMMs

Tags: r, residuals, glmm

Investigating how sound the fit was from R lme4::glmer.nb(), I tried plotting
the response variable against prediction plus residual.
I found they didn't exactly match.
Can you explain why there is a mismatch?
Am I omitting some other component from the sum (e.g. random Effects)?
How worried should I be about this?
Also, why could I not just work out the residuals as, residuals = value - prediction?

The code below reproduces the problem.
The first part is from the ?glmer.nb() example.

```
## Example
library(lme4)
set.seed(101)
dd <- expand.grid(f1 = factor(1:3),
f2 = LETTERS[1:2], g=1:9, rep=1:15,
KEEP.OUT.ATTRS=FALSE)
summary(mu <- 5*(-4 + with(dd, as.integer(f1) + 4*as.numeric(f2))))
dd$y <- rnbinom(nrow(dd), mu = mu, size = 0.5)
str(dd)

require("MASS")## and use its glm.nb() - as indeed we have zero random effect:
m.glm <- glm.nb(y ~ f1*f2, data=dd, trace=TRUE)
summary(m.glm)

m.nb <- glmer.nb(y ~ f1*f2 + (1|g), data=dd, verbose=TRUE)
m.nb

## Plot mismatch
par(mfrow=c(3,3))
plot( log(dd$y), predict(m.nb), log='' ); abline(0,1)
plot( log(dd$y), predict(m.nb)+resid(m.nb), log='' ); abline(0,1)

## also for MASS::glm.nb(()
plot( log(dd$y), predict(m.glm)+resid(m.glm), log='' ); abline(0,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the default type of residual returned by `resid()` for a GLMM in **lme4** is the *deviance* residual (the contribution of each observation to the model deviance), not a response residual.

If you want response residuals, which are deviations of observations from the modelled expectation of the response, then use `type = 'response'` in your `resid()` call.

In a GLMM in **lme4**, the response residual is literally defined as:

```
> lme4:::residuals.glmResp
....
        response = y - mu
....
```

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. In my case, I'm not interested in the random effects as such, I just want to regress them out in order to obtain values (residuals) whose mean does not vary with the category of those RE factors. So I'll be using  resid(fit, type = 'response').